# IPB4 - Where are the group names stored?

Tags: php, mysql, ipb, invision-power-board

https://invisionpower.com/

I'm building an application that requires groups to be dynamically created in the IPB 4 Forums back end. This is easily accomplished by adding a new row in the core_groups table.

However, I can't find where to change the name of a newly created group.

I've looked in the core_groups table and a bunch of other places. I'm at a loss as to where the group names are stored in the DB (if at all).

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. IPB4 stores all its "words" in a global word table. Each of the controllers search this table when they need a "word".

SQL

> SELECT * FROM ipb.core_sys_lang_words where word_key like "%core_group_%";

So you want to search the table for the "core_group_" prefix in the word_key column.

So when you're inserting the a new row into the groups table, you'll want to make sure you get the insert ID and make a new word with a wordkey "core_group_{groupid}".